# How do i get consume to work here for this key Event?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtextfield, keyevent

I double checked to make sure that it wasn't the condition that was the problem but for some reason consume refuses to work

I have no idea what i'm supposed to do

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                    System.out.println("Key is a Letter");
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it inside of the `keyTyped` method instead, since `keyTyped` executes when the key is sent by the keyboard to system input.

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
        System.out.println("Key is a Letter");
        e.consume();
    }
}
```